# Require guidance on implementing Excel services in SharePoint 2013 for existing Excel sheets and logic

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We have excel reports with programming built in to connect to db and extract info.

The sheet has 1000 rows. Every 5 rows belong to 1 client.. So there are total 200 clients (1000 rows). The excel sheet has functionality that allows user to filter the data based on client name.

This sheet is now going to be uploaded to SharePoint. Can the filter functionality be invoked via SharePoint 2013? Say based on some drop-down on the SharePoint page OR based on the logged in user's (AD) Company name. Please guide on the approach to follow...

We have set up Excel Services on our SharePoint site as a first step to this by following [this MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219698.aspx)...

More reference articles:-

http://blogs.technet.com/b/microsoft_in_education/archive/2013/05/16/parameterizing-an-excel-spreadsheet.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/connect-filter-web-parts-to-excel-web-access-HA010105470.aspx

http://blogs.office.com/2008/01/16/personalized-data-in-excel-services/?Redirected=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to this question in [this link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/connect-filter-web-parts-to-excel-web-access-HA010105470.aspx). It is for SharePoint 2010, but can be used in SharePoint 2013 as well (with very minor changes).

To create named range and to define a parameter in Excel 2013: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/share-workbooks-using-excel-services-HA102772301.aspx#_Toc364261323